# Estimating the training time in convolutional neural network

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to know whether it is possible to estimate the training time of a convolutional neural network, given parameters like depth, filter, size of input, etc.

For instance, I am working on a 3D convolutional neural network whose structure is like:

- a (20x20x20) convolutional layer with stride of 1 and 8 filters
- a (20x20x20) max-pooling layer with stride of 20
- a fully connected layer mapping to 8 nodes
- a fully connected layer mapping to 1 output

I am running 100 epochs and print the loss(mean squared error) every 10 epochs. Now it has run 24 hours and no loss printed(I suppose it has not run 10 epochs yet). By the way, I am not using GPU.

Is it possible to estimate the training time like a formula or something like that? Is it related to time complexity or my hardware? I also found the following paper, will it give me some information?

https://ai2-s2-pdfs.s3.amazonaws.com/140f/467566e799f32831db6913d84ccdbdcac0b2.pdf

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, it completely depends on the hardware and size of the dataset. You can just estimate time in one epoch and multiply for the number of epochs you want to train.

Comment: Thanks. Then how do I estimate time in one epoch?

Comment: Just run training for one epoch and then measure time.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I will try it, though it has run for a day...

Comment: It should also be mentioned that there is no details in the question, like framework/programming language or even the device you are training. If you want it to be fast, use a GPU.

Comment: Sorry. I am using tensorflow, and the device is Mac Pro(2009) with OS X Yosemite, 2 x 2.56 GHz Quad-Core Intel Xeon, 32 GB 1066 MHz DDR3 ECC, NVIDIA GeForce GT 120 512MB, which I don't think I can use to accelerate, according to the list (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus).